# Find possibilities for order of an element in a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gcd-and-lcm

Question: If $|a^5| =  12$, what are the possibilities for $|a|$? If $|a^4| = 12$, what are the possibilities for $|a|$?

Now my approach was using the fact that $|a^k| = \frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$
So that the first one for example, $12 = \frac{n}{\gcd(n,5)} \implies \gcd(n,5) = \frac{n}{12}$, so $n = 5*12$ and $n = 60$.
Similarly for the second, $12 = \frac{n}{\gcd(n,4)} \implies \gcd(n,4) = \frac{n}{12}$, so $n = 4*12$ and $n = 48$.

Is there a smarter way to go about this or a fact I'm not using that would make this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible values of $\gcd(n,k)$ are exactly the divisors of $k$.

1. The possible values of $\gcd(n,5)$ are $1,5$. Hence $n = 12 \gcd(n,5) = 12,60$.
2. The possible values of $\gcd(n,4)$ are $1,2,4$. Hence $n=12 \gcd(n,4) =12, 24, 48$.

You still need to test those candidates. In the second case, only $n=48$ works.

Comment: A stronger result is possible in the second case. If $n = 12\gcd(n,4)$ then $n$ must be divisible by $4$ so $\gcd(n,4) = 4$ and $n = 48$.

Comment: @Zoe, indeed!..